# How to stop product image changing with wrong swatch?

Tags: configurable-product, simple-product, swatches

I have my swatches setup with labels so that when a colour is called, it displays the right image. My problem is with my size attributes, they revert my image back to the base image when selected.
There is no way I could add each image to the simple product, I have over 20,000 variations.

Is there not a simple way to say, if the swatch is selected and it does not match a label then do nothing. (instead of reverting to base image)
Alternatively I thought I could also have....If anything other than my Product Colour swatch is selected, then do nothing.

I don't know where I would implement this or how I would do it. I need help.

Comment: anyone? :( :( :( :(